# Retrieving files from sql database into read or write mode

Tags: java, android, sql, listview

i am new to android, i am developing an app similar to Notepad. My notepad files are saved in the form of ListView, where the listview contains a TextView and a button. Button is for delete option to remove data from the database, which it is working successfully, but the problem is with the TextView, my intention is when a user clicks any file in the listview (i.e.,TextView), i want to open that file without losing previous data written in notepad, so that he can update the data. Any help is appreciated.

This is my java file,

```
public void deleteTask(View view) {
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?",
            new String[]{task});
    db.close();
    updateUI();
}
```

and

```
    public void click(View view) {
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());

    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    db.openDatabase( getDatabasePath(task), SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory null,int flags);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

This is my xml file

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:onClick="click"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/task_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:onClick="deleteTask"/>
```

and another xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.shiva.secretbook.TodoList">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_todo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I think this code is enough to solve my question. Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I want to open the saved file from database when a user clicks on list view, so that he can view and update the data as from user wish@ Mick Mnemonic